# Tornado async request timeout - how to check that user is still connected

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to code a web chat using the tornado.

The client (user) sends a long post request, during which I send him messages in response. But I am having problems with checking whether the user is online.

When a user sign out or simply close the tab / browser - everything is simple, executed `on_connection_close()` and I understand that it is disconnected, but if **the client lost the Internet connection**, then **`on_connection_close` does not work**.

How can I check, whether the user is online?

Comment: I have edited your question so it is easily understandable. Please review and edit it if you think you asked something else than I assumed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take look at [tornadio2](https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio2) which is Tornado+Socket.io, and [implement multiplex connection](https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio2/tree/master/examples/multiplexed), one to handle to push messages, the other is to ping the server so that you can check if the client is still connected or not.

The multiplex does not open multiple connections but uses the single connection to virtually connect to different Handlers. Look at multiplexed.py line 66.

```
class RouterConnection(SocketConnection):
    __endpoints__ = {'/chat': ChatConnection,
                 '/ping': PingConnection}
```

The multiplex example is also an sample chat application